# Pygame - TypeError: invalid rect assigment

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to make a platformer game. Since I'm new to pygame library, I'm following a video tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8ui5HK3oSiGXM2Pc2DahNu1xXBf7WQh-). And I ran to a problem. I checked documentation, tutorials, I even found somebody here that asked the same question. But nothing worked. So what did I do wrong and how can I repair it?

Player class:

```
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill((0,0,255))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
```

This is level code in which I'm drawing the player now. I will change it.

```
import pygame
from tiles import Tile
from settings import tileSize
from player import Player

class Level:
    #setup
    def __init__(self, levelData, surface):
        self.displaySurface = surface
        self.setupLevel(levelData)
        self.worldShift = 0
    
    def setupLevel(self,layout):
        self.tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()

        for rowIndex, row in enumerate(layout):
            for colIndex, col in enumerate(row):
                x = colIndex * tileSize
                y = row * tileSize
                if col == 'X':
                    tile = Tile((x,y),tileSize)
                    self.tiles.add(tile)
                if col == 'P':
                    playerSprite = Player((x,y))
                    self.player.add(playerSprite)
    def run(self):
        #level tiles
        self.tiles.update(self.worldShift)
        self.tiles.draw(self.displaySurface)
        #player
        self.player.draw(self.displaySurface)
```

This is error message:

```
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.htmlTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\AdkoaMisko-game\main\window.py", line 10, in <module>     
    level = Level(levelMap,screen)
  File "d:\AdkoaMisko-game\main\level.py", line 10, in __init__      
    self.setupLevel(levelData)
  File "d:\AdkoaMisko-game\main\level.py", line 25, in setupLevel    
    playerSprite = Player((x,y))
  File "d:\AdkoaMisko-game\main\player.py", line 8, in __init__      
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = pos)
TypeError: invalid rect assignment
```

Comment: What prints the `pos` value before you assign it to the `topleft` argument ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit -- the `pos` value isn't printed anywhere. Why?

Comment: Yes I meant have you checked the value `pos` were valid before using it as argument ? (so I assumed you had tried to print it somewhere to control that). Anyway problem seemd to be solved :), and that the pos value was malformed indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is a list of columns. The index of the row is `rowIndex`:

<s>`y = row * tileSize`</s>

```py
y = rowIndex * tileSize
```